# Android - multi value EditText

Tags: android

I want to implement a multi-value `EditText` (just like Tags filed in StackOverFlow question)

for now, I am asking the user to press a button so the value will be stored and the `EditText` will be cleared then the user will need to enter the next value. And I think this reflects a very poor user experience.

is there any better practice to approach this?

Comment: use separator like commas?

Comment: Like @RandykaYudhistira make use of delimiters. Take a look at String.split http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement a multi-value EditText (just like Tags filed in StackOverFlow question)

You need to make use of [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html) control to achieve this

Example

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete_7);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
         textView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Comment: @MahmoudKhateeb this works in the same way, like tags in SO. what do you want then?

Comment: MultiAutoCompleteTextView provide multiple suggestions for substrings, it's not multi value.